# Can't get file size with fstat() or lseek() using file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, bash, file, file-io

Trying to `open()` a file and then get size with `lseek()` or `fstat()` but both are resulting in a size of `0`

For example, my line:

> printf("lseek size : %d\nfstat size : %d\nfile desc: %d\n", fileSize,
>   mystat.st_size, fd);

using a file **data1** with contents:

```
Jacobs-MBP:Desktop Kubie$ cat data1
2.3
3.1
5.3
1.1
```

prints:

```
Jacobs-MBP:Desktop Kubie$ ./a.out 4 data1
byte size: 4
Opened: data1
lseek size : 0
fstat size : 0
file desc: 3
```

Below is my program, intent is to `mmap()` file into memory for other purposes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

        int fd;
        struct stat mystat;
        void * pmap;
        int fileSize;

        if (argc < 3) { printf("wrong # args\n"); return 0; }
        if (argc > 3) { printf("wrong # args\n"); return 0; }

        sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &byteSize);

        printf("byte size: %d\n", byteSize);

        fd = open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_TRUNC);
        if (fd == -1) {
                perror("Error opening file!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
                printf("Opened: %s\n", argv[2]);
        }

        if (fstat(fd, &mystat) < 0)  {
                perror("fstat error!");
                close(fd);
                exit(1);
        }

        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        fileSize = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);

        printf("lseek size : %d\nfstat size : %d\nfile desc: %d\n", fileSize, mystat.st_size, fd);

        pmap = mmap(0, fileSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        if (pmap == MAP_FAILED) {
                perror("mmap error!");
                close(fd);
                exit(1);
        }

        return 0;

}
```

I also noticed that the contents of `data1` file are erased on completion of this program.

Really a newbie with C so any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Code does not even compile (e.g. `byteSize` not defined anywhere) - please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulR I apologize, not sure why this would happen as it compiles on my machine... double-checking now

Comment: You also need to enable compiler warnings, e.g. there is at least one `printf` format string error that the compiler will helpfully point out for you if you let it (`st_size` is not an `int` so you should not use `%d` for this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)

```
   O_TRUNC
          If  the  file  already  exists  and  is a regular file and the open mode allows writing (i.e., is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) it will be truncated to
          length 0.  If the file is a FIFO or terminal device file, the O_TRUNC flag is ignored.  Otherwise the effect of O_TRUNC is unspecified.
```

your code does

```
fd = open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_TRUNC);
```

and as per description above

*If  the  file  already  exists  and  is a regular file and the open mode allows writing (i.e., is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) it will be truncated to length 0*